# Function returns JSONP. How to display as JSON - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am working with an API from another website and I am trying to get a JSON object back. Unfortunately due to the site origin issue I have to use JSONP to retrieve my data.

The function is working but I am stack on how to sanitize the data coming as a JSONP format to be able to use it as JSON?

This is my function

```
$('.loginForm').click(function(){
    var url = 'https//api.example.com';
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: jsonpCallback,
        success: jsonpCallback,
        jsonp: "callback"
    });

    function jsonpCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
    }   
});
```

**EDIT**
This is the response I get before the error

```
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", more...}
```

And this is the error i'm getting

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement


{"accountID":1328031,"authToken":"D81CDCB......
```

I went through every post in SO and the web in general to find where I am making a mistake but so far I can't find anything.

Comment: Please specify the api you are trying to use

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: Are you sure the api supports jsonp?

Comment: this is the response `Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", more...}`

Comment: @JasonP if the API doesn't support jsonp what other options do I have to get the data back? I tried XMLHttpRequest() but I was getting into the Access-Origin issues with it so I wanted to try doing it with jQuery

Comment: If the api doesn't support jsonp, you have the usual options... the best are probably CORS (if the server supports it) or a server-side proxy.

Comment: If they do not support CORS and they do not support JSONP than you are out of luck on the Ajax front. You would need to use a serverside proxy or a service like Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: They do support it. Based on their documentation I can use their API with fopen() in php or XMLHttpRequest() with JS

Comment: @JonathanLonowski can you plese provide an example of CORS? I tried a few but did not work.

Comment: @Geo Is their documentation public so you can share it? If they support cross-origin, they may ask that you register your app's origin for CORS or use a different `callback` parameter name than jQuery's default for JSONP. (And, CORS is transparent to an `XMLHttpRequest` client. It's all managed on the server.)

Comment: I registered my company with them and I have an authentication key and everything. If I run the api URL directly in a browser i receive back JSON data on screen

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the response in jsonP then you can use jXHR for making cross domain request , below is the link of jXHR (Library) :

https://gist.github.com/1576277/f4aead6741e0d7b0c40db6601048d9db6be1a5f9

And here is an example to use jXHR :

```
function sendRequest()
{
    var xhrReq = new jXHR();
    xhrReq.onreadystatechange = function(data)
    {
        if (xhrReq.readyState === 4) 
        {
            //data contains your jsonp response..
        }
    };
    var url = "http://" + SERVER_NAME + "yourCodeFile.aspx?callback=?"; 
    xhrReq.open("GET",url);
    xhrReq.send();
}
```

Always remember to add **'callback=?'** as a query string parameter in url for jXHR request as the respone is jsonP.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am trying to avoid libraries. I am pretty sure there is a way to do it without one

Comment: Try adding `"callback=?"` as a query string parameter in your url like this : `https//api.example.com?callback=?`

Answer (score 0):

try using JSON.parse

```
function jsonpCallback(response){
    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
}
```

Comment: tried that and is giving me an error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`